# Plot two columns against each other given a value in a third column

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a large dataframe of stock prices:

```
stock_data.head()

       date     open     high    low    close   volume      Name

0   2013-02-08  15.07   15.12   14.63   14.75   8407500     AAL
1   2013-02-11  14.89   15.01   14.26   14.46   8882000     AAL
2   2013-02-12  14.45   14.51   14.10   14.27   8126000     AAL
3   2013-02-13  14.30   14.94   14.25   14.66   10259500    AAL
4   2013-02-14  14.94   14.96   13.16   13.99   31879900    AAL
```

If I wanted to select apple shares for e.g. out of this large dataset I would do:

```
aapl = stock_data.loc[stock_data['Name']=='AAPL']
```

Which provides:

```
aapl.head()

           date      open    high     low    close   volume     Name

1259    2013-02-08  67.7142 68.4014 66.8928 67.8542 158168416   AAPL
1260    2013-02-11  68.0714 69.2771 67.6071 68.5614 129029425   AAPL
1261    2013-02-12  68.5014 68.9114 66.8205 66.8428 151829363   AAPL
1262    2013-02-13  66.7442 67.6628 66.1742 66.7156 118721995   AAPL
1263    2013-02-14  66.3599 67.3771 66.2885 66.6556 88809154    AAPL
```

I've tried calling this a new `df` to make the `date` column the index to then call `plt.plot()` but it didn't seem to work out.

How can I plot two columns against each other given these selected rows? For e.g. to plot the `date` column against the `open` column given `stock_data['Name'] == AAPL`?

And for further filtering, how can I change the values to be something like the mean `open` values by week/month/year etc?

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried using `plt.plot()` that did not work, and explain in what way "it didn't seem to work out". Did you get an error? the wrong plot?

Comment: Are you looking for `aapl.set_index('date')['open'].plot()`